# 'npm install' in a Dockerfile doesn't install any dependencies

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

It's kind of weird, I didn't see any errors when run `docker-compose build` but when I access into container, I didn't see `node_modules` folder, just only `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.
Any the logs when I run `docker-compose build` show normally. For example:

```
....
added 552 packages from 678 contributors and audited 4007 packages in 11.2s
found 0 vulnerabilities
....
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

ENV APP_PATH /app
WORKDIR $APP_PATH

COPY ./app_front/package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g ts-node typescript
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

And `docker-compose` file

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: racer_mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxx
          MYSQL_USER: "xxxx"
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        expose:
          - "3306"
        volumes:
          - ./docker/database:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./docker/mysql_init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    app_front:
        container_name: app_front
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./docker/app_front/Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./app_front:/app_front
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
```

**Note:**
But when I add multiple commands  in `docker-compose`, it works. But I want to install packages in `Dockerfile`, not `docker-compose` file.

```
       command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c
          - |
            npm install
            npm start
```

My problem is exactly the same with this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1005), I have tried, but without success.
Any advice is welcomed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you build your `App` in `/app_front/` folder in build Process then you delete  ""overwriting" all the files in that folder by using :

```
volumes:
          - ./app_front:/app_front
```

in your `compose` , I suggest you to remove the `volumes` section and try again.

Comment: I have the other question. If I delete volumes section, it worked, but when I changed my code, it didn't auto-restart server by nodemon?

Comment: Please open new Post for new questions, that is not a related question.

Answer (score 4):

What might be happening is `COPY . .` is overwriting your node_modules directory in the image. Create a `.dockerignore` file in the same directory as your Dockerfile and ignore `node_modules`.